# Cancan: trying to restrict access to Controller with no Model of the same name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I have a `FooController` but no model Foo - it's a gateway to a third-party service. In `FooController`, the resource being accessed by the `do_bar` method is a `baz`. Currently anyone can manage anyone else's `baz`, through the `FooController` and I want to restrict management to just their own.

In my ability.rb, I've written the following into the `initialize` method:

```
can :manage, :foo
```

But what I want to do is write something like this (of course this doesn't work):

```
can :manage, :foo
  @baz.user == user
end
```

FooController:

```
load_resource :baz, find_by: :user_data, parent: false

def do_bar
  @baz = Baz.find(params[:user_data]) #necessary otherwise @baz is nil
  authorize! :manage, :foo

  #other stuff
end
```

I essentially want to make it so that the @baz instance - which is being manipulated in the `FooController`, must be owned by that user for them to be able to manage it.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Define the ability about Baz.

```
can :manage, Baz, :user => user
```

2.You can authorize manually in action.

```
#load_resource :baz, find_by: :user_data, parent: false

def do_bar
  @baz = Baz.find(params[:user_data]) #necessary otherwise @baz is nil
  authorize! :manage, @baz

  #other stuff
end
```

Comment: That was it. Cheers, mate